# Find date within strings using regex in both Python and grep

Tags: python, regex, unix, grep

I have a log with entries in the following format:

```
1483528632  3   1   Wed Jan  4 11:17:12 2017    501040002   4
1533528768  4   2   Thu Jan  5 19:17:45 2017    534040012   3
...
```

How do I fetch only the timestamp component (eg. `Wed Jan  4 11:17:12 2017`) using regular expressions?

I have to implement the final product in python, but the requirement is to have part of an automated regression suite in bash/perl (with the final product eventually being in Python).

Comment: I've to implement the final product in python, but the requirement is to have a part of automated regression suite in bash/perl so I stated that as grep, unix, regex but it will eventually be in python.

Answer (score 1):

If the format is fixed in terms of space delimiters, you can simply [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), get a slice of a date string and load it to `datetime` object via [`datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior):

```
In [1]: from datetime import datetime

In [2]: s = "1483528632  3   1   Wed Jan  4 11:17:12 2017    501040002   4"

In [3]: date_string = ' '.join(s.split()[3:8])

In [4]: datetime.strptime(date_string, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
Out[4]: datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 4, 11, 17, 12)
```

Comment: I've spaces varying and even at some entries it is tab delimited data

Answer (score 1):

**The regex** to match the timestamp is:

`'[a-zA-Z]{3} +[a-zA-Z]{3} +\d{1,2} +\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} +\d{4}'`.

**With grep** that can be used like this (if your log file was called `log.txt`):

```
$ grep -oE '[a-zA-Z]{3} +[a-zA-Z]{3} +\d{1,2} +\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} +\d{4}' log.txt
# Wed Jan  4 11:17:12 2017
# Thu Jan  5 19:17:45 2017
```

**In python** you can use that like so:

```
import re

log_entry = "1483528632  3   1   Wed Jan  4 11:17:12 2017    501040002   4"

pattern = '[a-zA-Z]{3} +[a-zA-Z]{3} +\d{1,2} +\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} +\d{4}'
compiled = re.compile(pattern)
match = compiled.search(log_entry)
match.group(0)
# 'Wed Jan  4 11:17:12 2017'
```

You can use this to get an actual datetime object from the string (expanding on above code):

```
from datetime import datetime
import re

log_entry = "1483528632  3   1   Wed Jan  4 11:17:12 2017    501040002   4"

pattern = '[a-zA-Z]{3} +[a-zA-Z]{3} +\d{1,2} +\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} +\d{4}'
compiled = re.compile(pattern)
match = compiled.search(log_entry)

log_time_str = match.group(0)
datetime.strptime(log_time_str, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
# datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 4, 11, 17, 12)
```

Answer (score 1):

Grep is most often used in this scenario if you are working with syslog.  But as the post is also tagged with Python.  This example uses *regular expressions* with [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
import re
```

Define the pattern to match:

```
pat = "\w{3}\s\w{3}\s+\w\s\w{2}:\w{2}:\w{2}\s\w{4}"
```

Then use re.findall to return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in txt:

```
re.findall(pat,txt)
```

Output:

```
['Wed Jan  4 11:17:12 2017', 'Thu Jan  5 19:17:45 2017']
```

---

If you want to then use [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html):

```
import datetime

dates = re.findall(pat,txt)

datetime.datetime.strptime(dates[0], "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
```

Output:

```
datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 4, 11, 17, 12)
```

You can then utilise these datetime objects:

```
dateObject = datetime.datetime.strptime(dates[0], "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y").date()
timeObject = datetime.datetime.strptime(dates[0], "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y").time()

print('The date is {} and time is {}'.format(dateObject,timeObject))
```

Output:

```
The date is 2017-01-04 and time is 11:17:12
```

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches: with and without using *regular expressions*
**1)** using `re.findall()` function:

```
with open('test.log', 'r') as fh:
    lines = re.findall(r'\b[A-Za-z]{3}\s[A-Za-z]{3}\s{2}\d{1,2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \d{4}\b',fh.read(), re.M)

print(lines)
```

**2)** usign `str.split()` and `str.join()` functions:

```
with open('test.log', 'r') as fh:
    lines = [' '.join(d.split()[3:8]) for d in fh.readlines()]

print(lines)
```

The output in both cases will be a below:

```
['Wed Jan  4 11:17:12 2017', 'Thu Jan  5 19:17:45 2017']
```

Answer (score -1):

```
grep -E '\b(Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun) (Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) +[0-9]+ [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} [0-9]{4}\b' dates
```

Answer (score -1):

If you just wanted to list the dates, rather than grep, perhaps:

```
sed -nre 's/^.*([A-Za-z]{3}\s+[A-Za-z]{3}\s+[0-9]+\s+[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+\s+[0-9]{4}).*$/\1/p' filename
```